# Aggregate data from different micro batches in Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to aggregate and find some metrics using Spark streaming (Reading from Kafka) every minute. I am able to aggregate the data for that particular minute. How do I make sure I can have a bucket for current day and sum up all the aggregate values of all minutes in that day?

I have a data frame and I am doing something similar to this.

```
sampleDF = spark.sql("select userId,sum(likes) as total from likes_dataset group by userId order by userId")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the use of "[Watermarking](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking)" feature from Structured Streaming Programming

Sample code

```
import spark.implicits._

val words = ... // streaming DataFrame of schema { timestamp: Timestamp, word: String }

    val windowedCounts = words
        .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")
        .groupBy(
            window($"timestamp", "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
            $"word")
        .count()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried doing it. Spark is not retaining the previous micro batch value. If I have micro batch interval of 60 seconds and if I try to create window of 10 minutes, the values at 12:01:00 is not getting aggregated with values of 12:02:00. For 12:02:00, it is only finding the aggregates on recently received data. How do I store aggregated data for all the 10 minutes?

Comment: I have main function which gets data from Kafka stream. And, it calls a function for each RDD. Inside this function, I do aggregate the values. But for every RDD, the aggregate values are reset. Previously aggregated values don't stay. I don't know how I can define a global aggregate data frame for this spark session life and combine all the aggregate data. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what's going on. I got to know about stateful streaming in Spark and that helped me.

All I had to do is,

```
running_counts = countStream.updateStateByKey(updateTotalCount, initialRDD=initialStateRDD)
```

where I had to write this updateTotalCount function to say how to merge the old aggregate data with new aggregate data of micro batch. In my case, the update function looks like this:

```
def updateTotalCount(currentCount, countState):
    if countState is None:
       countState = 0
    return sum(currentCount) + countState
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain a bit more on `countState`, what does it have? and also your `countStream` has a stream of RDD's? how do you get `initialRDD` and `initialStateRDD`?